# Microsoft Graph ASP.NET MVC 5 Send Mail throwing unknown error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, microsoft-graph-api

Been working on an ASP.NET MVC 5 application that interacts with the MS Graph API.

The controller gets a graph client for the current user and then using that client sends an email.

```
public class EmailController : Controller
{
    // GET: Email
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        var client = await MSGraphServiceClient.GetGraphServiceClientAsync();
        await InvitationHelper.SendEmail(client);


        return Content("");
    }
}

public static async Task<GraphServiceClient> GetGraphServiceClientAsync()
    {
        string appId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
        string appKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientSecret"];
        string aadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"];
        // Get Signed in user
        string signedInUserID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
        // Get app and user id claims from Azure
        string tenantID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid").Value;
        string userObjectID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;
        // Specify Graph resource URL
        string graphResourceID = "https://graph.microsoft.com";

        // get a token for the Graph without triggering any user interaction (from the cache, via multi-resource refresh token, etc)
        ClientCredential clientcred = new ClientCredential(appId, appKey);
        // initialize AuthenticationContext with the token cache of the currently signed in user, as kept in the app's database
        AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(aadInstance + tenantID, new ADALTokenCache(signedInUserID));
        AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(graphResourceID, clientcred, new UserIdentifier(userObjectID, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));

        // use delegate to create auth provider using async auth result
        var delegateAuthProvider = new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((requestMessage) =>
        {
            requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", authenticationResult.AccessToken);
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        });

        // return the graph service client
        return new GraphServiceClient(delegateAuthProvider);
    }

    public static async Task<bool> SendEmail(GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient)
    {

            var message = new Message()
            {
                Subject = "Test",
                Body = new ItemBody()
                {
                    ContentType = BodyType.Text,
                    Content = "This is a test"
                },
                ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>() { new Recipient() { EmailAddress = new EmailAddress() { Address = "jonathan.sweetland@gmail.com" } } }
            };
            var request = graphServiceClient.Me.SendMail(message, true).Request();
            await request.PostAsync();

            return true;
}
```

It is not a permissions error because on AAD I have granted all the permissions for this app. I have other graph calls working so I know it authenticates correctly using the same code.

[image: Error]

[image: Stack trace]

Comment: I'd suggest using Fiddler to sniff out what is actually coming back down the wire. Often times the response's JSON payload will provide a clearer picture of what is going under the covers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used fiddler as was suggested and the JSON response was the same as the error messages displayed.

After a lot of playing around, I found that if you try and use the SendMail on the Graph API whilst authenticated by a Azure Active Directory tenant that is not set up with an outlook account. Even if the account has an outlook account on a different tenant, then you will not be able to use the SendMail endpoint.